# Git commit including local merge

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I have a question situation in git where a commit is including a previous feature branch commit in a new commit for a feature branch that the first feature branch was merged to.

To explain further:

1. Create a feature branch from master, call it feature 1. Feature1 code is added, committed and pushed to git.
2. While waiting for merge from feature1 to master, another branch is created from master, call it feature2. I merge feature1 into feature2 locally so I have the latest code to work with.
3. Feature1 is merged into master
4. Now when I go to add, commit, push and merge feature2 into master, the commit for feature1 is included in feature2 even though feature1 is already merged with master.

Is got smart enough to ignore that second commit for feature1 or can I run a git command locally prior to the feature2 push so that it knows it can ignore the feature1 branch?

Comment: Git is quite smart. Will not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Git tracks commits by their their unique identifiers, so if you merge two branches that contain the *same* commits (with the same commit IDs) you don't actually get "double commits". Git just records that you have commit `1`, `2`, and `3` in your new branch, even if `1` might also exist in another. So, when you merge back, you'd (essentially) get commits `2` and `3`.